# Java How do you clear kidCache?

Tags: java, preferences

The Java class`Preferences` has a HashMap property called `kidCache`.  When executing the `Preferences` method `remove(String node)` the node is effectively removed from the user's preferences file, but not from the `kidCache` property.
Consequently when I print to the console `prefs.nodeExists("account-1")` or `Arrays.toString(prefs.childrenNames())`, it is still showing as being available.  It only finally clears when the current program finishes executing.

```
public class ClassA {
    private Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("TestNode");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassA();
    }

    public ClassA() {
        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("TestNode/account-1");
        prefs.put("username", "testUser1");
        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("TestNode");
        prefs.remove("account-1/"); // node removed here
        try {
            System.out.println(prefs.nodeExists("account-1")); // a test for its existance still outputs 'true'
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(prefs.childrenNames())); // kidCache can be retrieved with this method
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58572', transport: 'socket'
true
[account-1]
```

I tried using `prefs.flush()` but that didn't work.  How do you completely clear the subNodes before the program has finished executing?

Comment: Could you be looking for the [`sync()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#sync--) method?

Comment: no `sync( )` did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue.  Though I haven't figured out  how ot manually clear the kidCache, the proper way of removing a node is by setting the path to the node and then using the `removeNode()` method instead of the `remove(String node)` method one level up.

```
public class ClassA {
    private Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("TestNode");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassA();
    }

    public ClassA() {
        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("TestNode/account-1");
        prefs.put("username", "testUser1");
        prefs.removeNode();
        prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("TestNode");
        try {
            System.out.println(prefs.nodeExists("account-1")); // a test for its existence now outputs 'false'
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58572', transport: 'socket'
false
```